# Looping with a DEC

Tags: assembly, masm, cpu-registers, masm32

I am having an issue with a MASM32 program. I am trying to get this code to work:

```
.DATA
alfa dword 9

.CODE
start:

MOV ecx, alfa
MOV eax, 0

L1: ADD eax, ecx
DEC ecx
LOOP L1
CALL WRITEINT

exit
END start
```

I have found that the problem is only within the loop, everything else works fine. Can some please help me get the loop to work correctly, it does not return a value and doesn't exit. Is this supposed to happen? Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are decreasing `ecx` twice. The `dec` instruction will decrease it, and the `loop` instrucction also decreases it.

Either use

```
dec ecx
jne L1
```

or use

```
loop L1
```

The reason why it doesn't exit is the following

```
dec ecx ->  ecx = 8
loop l1 -> ecx = 7
dec ecx ->  ecx = 6
loop l1 -> ecx = 5
dec ecx ->  ecx = 4
loop l1 -> ecx = 3
dec ecx ->  ecx = 2
loop l1 -> ecx = 1
```

And here comes the catch!

```
dec ecx ->  ecx = 0   no condition
loop l1 -> ecx = 0xffffffff Loop will not break because it breaks on 0
dec ecx -> ecx = 0xfffffffe
loop l1 -> ecx = 0xfffffffd
...
```

... and so on. You get the idea. If you had used a debugger, you would have seen this after only a few iterations.

Actually `ecx` will reach 0 in this roundtrip, but it takes ***LONG*** time. :)

Comment: Thank you for the explination, I am new to this and just getting started, I sure do appreciate your help, I did not know that the LOOP instruction automatically decrements!

Comment: I recommend downloading the Intel Instruction manual. It is a very valuable resource. And also experiment with a debugger. You will need it a lot anyway and when you modify the code in memory, you can experiment with the instructions without the assemnbling cycle.

Answer (score 1):

`LOOP` already takes care of the decrement, so get rid of the `DEC ECX`, i.e. change:

```
DEC ecx
LOOP L1
```

to just:

```
LOOP L1
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I also needed to know why, but I now see that I am decremnting twice with the DEC and LOOP instructions.